# Two meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface always satisfy an irreducible polynomial equation

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have come across the following statement mentioned in the title in some notes but not able to offer any explanation for it/prove it:
Two meromorphic functions on a Riemann surface always satisfy an irreducible polynomial equation.

Is this always true and how do I prove it? It's been a while since I took a complex analysis course, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: surely there should be some algebraic/analytic/compactness condition on the surface?

Comment: For compact Riemann surfaces, I think it’s true. It follows from the factoriality of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, the fact that any nonconstant morphism of Riemann surfaces induces a finite extension for their fields of meromorphic functions, the fact that a nonconstant meromorphic function on a Riemann surface is the same as a nonconstant map to $\mathbb{P}^1$, and the fact that the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathbb{C}(x)$. Contrast this with, say, $z$ and $e^z$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Suggest you scan in the half a page that refers to your question. Or, just typeset it yourself and post into your question.

Comment: There is a good chance, somewhere in the notes your instructor assumed Riemann surfaces to be compact. Check if this indeed the case. If so, read the proof given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381532/two-non-constant-meromorphic-functions-over-a-connected-compact-riemann-surface).